# Having a message display based on state code on checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'm attempting to have a text message trigger when certain states are selected as the billing state. I have the message displaying, but it will only show up for one state. When I try to add others into the "var stateCode" I have no luck. Here is what I have so far. How should I go about adding other states that will trigger the message to display?

```
//Sales Tax Warning Script
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'show_prop_message' );

function show_prop_message() {
echo '<div class="prop65-warning woocommerce-warning" style="display:none;"><p 
style="font-size:9pt; padding:10px 10px; border:1px solid #d1d18e; background- 
color:#ffffb8;"><img src="https://emartmedia.com/images/bw6pt.png" /><strong> 
</strong> We are now required to collect sales tax in your state. To learn more 
and see if you are eligible for exemption, click here. <a 
href="https://www.p65warnings.ca.gov" target="_blank">Details</a></p></div>';
}

// Second Step
// Show or hide warning message based on billing and shipping state
// First trigger is fired on billing state selection in case the "Ship to a 
different address" checkbox is unselected
// Second trigger is fired if the "Ship to a different address" checkbox is ticked
// Initally the "display:none" hides the warning message by default

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'show_warning_message' );
function show_warning_message(){  
      ?> 

 <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        // Set the shipping state 2 char code (This selection will fire the warning message display)
        // Fires secondary if shipping state is set to California
    var stateCode = 'WI';


        $('select#billing_state').change(function(){

            selectedState = $('select#billing_state').val();

            if( selectedState == stateCode ){
                $('.prop65-warning').show();
            }
            else {
                $('.prop65-warning').hide();
            }
        });

    }); 
    </script>
    <script>

     jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

        // Set the billing state 2 char code (This selection will fire the warning message display)
        // Fires initially if billing state is California
        var stateCode = 'WI';


        $('select#billing_state').change(function(){

            selectedState = $('select#billing_state').val();

            if( selectedState == stateCode ){
                $('.prop65-warning').show();
            }
            else {
                $('.prop65-warning').hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding the states to an array and then using the `includes()` method to see  if the value matches one of the states. It would look something like this:

```
var stateCode = ['WI', 'NY', 'FL', 'CA'];

$('select#billing_state').change(function(){
    selectedState = $('select#billing_state').val();
    if( stateCode.includes(selectedState) ){
        $('.prop65-warning').show();
    }
    else {
        $('.prop65-warning').hide();
    }
});
```